# Amazon MWS Boto get_matching_product_for_id

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-mws

I am new to Python and Boto. I have successfully connected and retrieved results using boto for

```
mws = MWSConnection(accessKeyId,secretKey,Merchant=merchantId)
response = mws.list_matching_products(MarketplaceId=marketplaceId,Query="Shopkins")
```

I am trying to lookup an item by UPC now, here is my code:

```
mws = MWSConnection(accessKeyId,secretKey,Merchant=merchantId)
response = mws.get_matching_product_for_id(MarketplaceId=marketplaceId,IdType="UPC",IdList="013138304582")
```

I have tested the UPC in the Amazon MWS scratchpad to verify that it does produce a result. But when I run this with boto I get:

```
InvalidParameterValue
line 53, in <module>
response = mws.get_matching_product_for_id(MarketplaceId=marketplaceId,IdType="UPC",IdList="013138304582")
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\boto\mws\connection.py", line 158, in requires
return func(*args, **kw)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\boto\mws\connection.py", line 81, in wrapper
return func(self, *args, **kw)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\boto\mws\connection.py", line 252, in wrapper
return func(self, request, response, *args, **kw)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\boto\mws\connection.py", line 798, in get_matching_product_for_id
return self._post_request(request, kw, response)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\boto\mws\connection.py", line 323, in _post_request
response.reason, body)
boto.mws.exception.InvalidParameterValue: InvalidParameterValue: Bad Request 
One or more parameter values in the request is invalid.
Found duplicate value for IdList: 1
```

Here is the boto documentation from their website regarding the function:

```
MWSConnection.get_matching_product_for_id(*args, **kw)
MWS GetMatchingProductForId/2011-10-01 API call; quota=20 restore=20.00    Returns a list of products and their attributes, based on a list of Product IDs that you specify.
        Lists: IdList.Id Required: MarketplaceId+IdType+IdList
```

I can't figure out why this is happening, I feel this is some sort of syntax issue on my part, but can't seem to figure out what to do. In the Amazon MWS scratchpad It shows the request details as:

```
&IdType=UPC
&IdList.Id.1=013138304582 HTTP/1.1
```

I've tried changing IdList to IdList.Id and IdList.Id.1 - but that just gives me a syntax error in Python. I'm sure this is a simple fix for someone with experience. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IdList` is type `list` not `str`:

```
response = mws.get_matching_product_for_id(MarketplaceId=marketplaceId,IdType="UPC",IdList=["013138304582"])
```